# I don’t know how many kilometers there are between the airport and the city

Tags: word-order

> 1 I don’t know how many kilometers there are between the airport and
> the city.
>
> 2 I don’t know how many kilometers between the airport and the city
> there are.
>
> 3 I don’t know how many kilometers between the airport and the city
> are there.
>
> 4 I don’t know how many kilometers between the airport and the city
> are.

Which ones are wrong?

Comment: Some effort please... not just four sentences and "which is wrong".

Comment: "How many kilometres **it is**" ('it' being 'the distance').

Comment: I don't know how many kilometres it is between the airport and the city. ???

Comment: 1 is correct but why the rest is wrong I don't know

Comment: They're just 'not how we say it'.

Comment: @KateBunting 1) I don’t know how many kilometers THERE IS between the airport and the city. OR 2) I don’t know how many kilometers IT IS between the airport and the city.

Comment: What I told you back in February. [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+is+ten+miles+to%2Cthere+are+ten+miles+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) finds no instances at all of _there are ten miles to_.

Comment: But I don't mean "there are" I said "there is"

Comment: I wonder whether it should be I don’t know how many kilometers THERE IS between/IT IS between. And if both are correct what the difference is.